# dllexport does not export explicit function template instantiation definition

Tags: c++, mfc, dllexport, function-templates

I can instantiate and MFC-export a function, but am unable to instantiate a templated function. I need the template to be defined generically so I can instantiate it elsewhere in the translation unit.

The sample code shows using MFC `__declspec(dllexport)` to export these functions:

```
// ExportTmpldFunc.h
void __declspec( dllexport ) MyFunc(); // MFC exported function declaration

template< class T >
void __declspec( dllexport ) MyTmpldFunc(); // primary MFC exported function template declaration

// ExportTmpldFunc.cpp
#include "ExportTmpldFunc.h"

void MyFunc() // function definition implicitly instantiated
{}

template< class T >
void MyTmpldFunc() // function template defined, but not instantiated
{}

// attempt1 to instantiate
template<> void MyTmpldFunc< int >() // explicit function template specialization defined, but not instantiated for MSVC
{}

// attempt2 to instantiate
template void MyTmpldFunc< int >(); // explicit function template instantiation definition, but still not instantiated for MSVC
```

Exporting `MyFunc` works:
[image: MyFunc exported]

But my attempts to export `MyTmpldFunc` do not:
[image]

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: You need to add the `__declspec( dllexport )` to the instantiation as well

Comment: Exporting the instantiation too works. Thanks.